# Is it possible to make preview image while scroll video timeline like in Netflix app?

Tags: swift, avplayer, tvos

Is it possible to make peview image while listing video timeline, like in Netflix App with AVPlayer? 
[exmple here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g9ngVJbhTDvWABBt49T-QrSfA354bERa/view)

I found that `mp4` video has that preview window, but `m3u8` format has not it

```
func playVideo(cell:  MovieCell) {
    guard let urlVideo = URL(string: cell.movieSrc) else { return }

    // Create an AVPlayer, passing it the HTTP Live Streaming URL.
    let player = AVPlayer(url: urlVideo)

    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    self.present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called "Trick Play" and must be included in the HLS manifest for `AVPlayer` to handle this for you.

See the [Trick Play](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices#2969507) section in [HLS Authoring Specification for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/hls_authoring_specification_for_apple_devices):

> 6.1. I-frame playlists (EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF) MUST be provided to support scrubbing and scanning UI.